# MySql If else condition

Tags: mysql

Is there any possibility of introduce if else for the given mysql query? This query resulting into 4 columns. Can this be in a single column?

```
SELECT 
    IF(regression.execution_date >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1), '-','07', '-','01') AND regression.execution_date <= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '09', '-', '30'), CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1), '.', '1'), 0) AS 'Q1',
    IF(regression.execution_date >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1),'-','10','-','01') AND regression.execution_date <= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '12', '-', '31'), CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1), '.', '2'),0) AS 'Q2',
    IF(regression.execution_date >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '01', '-', '01') AND regression.execution_date <= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '03', '-', '31'), CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '.', '3'), 0) AS 'Q3',
    IF(regression.execution_date >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '04', '-', '01') AND regression.execution_date <= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '06', '-', '31'), CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '.', '4'), 0) AS 'Q4'
FROM
    regression
```

Solution:

Thanks all for your comments. I implemented with case and it worked.

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN regression.execution_date >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1), '-','07', '-','01') AND regression.execution_date <= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '09', '-', '30') THEN (CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1), '.', '1')) 
WHEN regression.execution_date >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1), '-','10', '-','01') AND regression.execution_date <= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '12', '-', '31') THEN (CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1), '.', '2')) 
WHEN regression.execution_date >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-','01', '-','01') AND regression.execution_date <= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '03', '-', '31') THEN (CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '.', '3')) 
WHEN regression.execution_date >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-','04', '-','01') AND regression.execution_date <= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '06', '-', '31') THEN (CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '.', '4')) 
END as 'Quarter'
FROM 
regression
```

Comment: You can either use nested IF or the CASE syntax.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Answer (score 0):

do you want to calculate the actual quater ?

use this:

```
SELECT QUARTER(now());
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT  QUARTER(now());
+----------------+
| QUARTER(now()) |
+----------------+
|              2 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT  QUARTER('2015-10_07');
+-----------------------+
| QUARTER('2015-10_07') |
+-----------------------+
|                     4 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: Thanks Bernd. I need custom fiscal quarter value based on the date range. For example .01-Jan-2016 To 31-Mar-2016 is called as Q3

Comment: Wait...maybe you can just subtract a certain fixed amount from each date to shift the quarters?

Comment: or is this ok ? - SELECT  ELT(QUARTER('2015-10_07'),3,4,1,1) AS quater;

Comment: SELECT  CONCAT(YEAR(now()),',', ELT(QUARTER('2015-10_07'),3,4,1,1)) AS quater; - to year and quater

Comment: Here is the range 01-Jul-2015 To 31-Sep-2015 - Q1, 01-Oct-2015 To 30-Dec-2015 - Q2, 01-Jan-2016 To 31-Mar-2016 - Q3, 01-Apr-2016 To 30-Jun-2016 - Q4

Comment: @ram - SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(now()),',', ELT(QUARTER('2015-10_07'),3,4,1,2)) AS quater; - to year and quater like your ranges

Answer (score 0):

Just shift your date by 7 months to get the custom quarters you want:

```
SELECT(QUARTER(DATE_SUB(execution_date, INTERVAL 7 MONTH)))
FROM regression
```

If you want to use your original approach, then keep reading.  I saw several problems/inefficiencies in your query which I attempted to correct.  First, because your query is on the `regression` table, you don't need to explicitly refer to this table when selecting columns, so I did away with this.  Second, you are trying to compare `execution_date` which is presumably a date type against strings, which is the type which `CONCAT()` outputs.  So I used `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert your hand built date strings into actual date types.  Finally, I replaced what would have been a nightmarish set of nested `IF` statements with a single `CASE` expression.

```
CASE WHEN execution_date >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1), '-', '07', '-', '01'), '%Y-%m-%d') AND
          execution_date <= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '09', '-', '30'), '%Y-%m-%d')
     THEN CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1), '.', '1')
     WHEN execution_date >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1), '-', '10', '-', '01'), '%Y-%m-%d') AND
          execution_date <= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '12', '-', '31'),'%Y-%m-%d')
     THEN CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1), '.', '2')
     WHEN execution_date >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '01', '-', '01'), '%Y-%m-%d') AND
          execution_date <= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '03', '-', '31'), '%Y-%m-%d')
     THEN CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '.', '3')
     WHEN execution_date >= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '04', '-', '01'), '%Y-%m-%d') AND
          execution_date <= STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', '06', '-', '31'), '%Y-%m-%d')
     THEN CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '.', '4')
     ELSE '0' END AS theQuarter
FROM regression
```